# What is the purpose of the "for" attribute?

Tags: html, angularjs

In this code taken from angular.org:

```
<script>
   function Ctrl($scope) {
     $scope.names = ['pizza', 'unicorns', 'robots'];
     $scope.my = { favorite: 'unicorns' };
   }
</script>
 <form ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <h2>Which is your favorite?</h2>
     <label ng-repeat="name in names" for="{{name}}">
       {{name}}
       <input type="radio"
              ng-model="my.favorite"
              ng-value="name"
              id="{{name}}"
              name="favorite">
     </label>
   <div>You chose {{my.favorite}}</div>
 </form>
```

the label element has a "for" statement. I can't find anything on the Angular.org site indicating what this is or how it is used. It's not listed under directives or functions.

Comment: Hint: It's not Angular related.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Added html label, but have left angular since the user was asking about Angular not realising it was an un-related attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding to the comments in the previous answer:

The `for` attribute is used to target the `input` when the `label` and input are separate, like so:

```
<label for="MyId">
  My Label
</label>

<input type="radio"
       id="MyId"
       name="favorite">
```

If you nest the `input` inside the `label` like your example:

```
<label>
  My Label

  <input type="radio"
         name="favorite">
</label>
```

Then you don't need the `for` attribute, it will automatically target the input inside the label.

Answer (score 4):

It's an HTML attribute used to help browsers see the field that a label is "attached" to.

Example: Try clicking on some labels and your browser will automatically focus on the input field that it is associated with.

[PS] It has nothing to do with Angular and more of HTML and accessibility.

Comment: That's cool. Learn something new each day. However, I should point out that I removed the "for" and when I clicked on the label, the option was still selected. So it probably doesn't have anything to do with clicking.

Comment: Maybe it was meant for older browers that didn't support clicking on the label?

Comment: This is also extremely important for blind people, who use screen readers: it allows associating an input field with a readable label, and thus knowing what this input field is for.

Comment: @AndroidDev - that is because you have the input INSIDE the label. If you put it outside the label, then that's where the `for` attribute works.

Comment: @Phill So in this case, the "for" attribute is not really being used correctly.

Comment: @AndroidDev I wouldn't say it's not being used correctly, it's just unnecessary. Accessibility is still perfectly valid when nesting inside the label, so it's just redundant, that's all.